# Postgres: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting below error for the simple postgres procedure.

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
> Position: 19

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.dummy(a integer)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (a);
$$;
```

Comment: Procedures are supported from Postgres 11. Maybe you have older Postgres

Comment: What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: oh it's  older version  8.2

Comment: 8.2 has been end-of-life [for ages](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), it should not be used any more. You should upgrade to Postgres 12 now.